# shortcut for active address bar in total commander

Tags: windows, total-commander

I use `Total Commander` as file manager tools and I'm beginner in it.
I have a problem: When I want change current directory and enter custom address in address bar, I must click at address bar by mouse then enter my address.
I want know there is any shortcut for active address bar without mouse or what define it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In total commander you can assign a shortcut to almost any possible action.

To create a shortcut for an action

Go to

`Configuration > Options > Misc > Redefine Hotkeys`

Select a key combination and (to answer your question) assign it following command:

```
cm_EditPath
```

[image]

If you want to find other command click on the magnifying glass and then you can filter commands:
for example: here are all commands that contain the word 'path'

[image]

For info, I remapped,

- left key to cm_GoToParent
- right key to  cm_GoToDir

this makes navigation really fast

Other usefull shortcuts:

- ALT+F1 : change left pane directory
- AlT+F2 : change right pane directory

if you change left directory to same drive as right, it will go automatically to the same folder.

Last tip, I use the quick search all the time to go quickly to a folder just by typing it's first letters.

[image]